# os.path.join for getting up level paths

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider you have the following code:
`os.path.abspath(os.path.join('../../', __file__))`

I am quite puzzled because currently, it is returning me the same path such in  `__file__` path.

Any idea why I don't get two levels up of the `__file__` path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__file__` is an absolute file path and so the join attempts something like the following:

```
os.path.join('../../', '/path/to/file')
```

Since the second argument is already an absolute path, all previous ones are ineffective.

Also note that `__file__` contains the file name itself so if you want to go two directories up you'd need to split that off. The easiest solution is to use [`pathlib.Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html):

```
Path(__file__).parents[2]
```

If you want to go `n` levels up you can use [`Path(__file__).parents[n]`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.parents).

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation (emphasis mine):

> os.path.join(path, *paths)
>
> Join one or more path components
>   intelligently. The return value is the concatenation of path and any
>   members of *paths with exactly one directory separator (os.sep)
>   following each non-empty part except the last, meaning that the result
>   will only end in a separator if the last part is empty. **If a component
>   is an absolute path, all previous components are thrown away and
>   joining continues from the absolute path component**.

`__file__` is an absolute path, so `join` ignores the preceding `../../`.

Comment: How can I achieve this is a similar way lets say I even want to go up 3 levels or more

Comment: 3 levels from *where*? There is no "up" from an absolute path to a file. If `__file__` names a *directory*, though, you can *append* the `../..` to `__file__`.

Answer (score 0):

After some more trial and error I think I found the best solution:

```
os.path.abspath(os.path.join(__file__, '../../'))
```

Comment: Now that's a pretty weird workaround which doesn't exactly achieve the highest level of readability. The result of `os.path.join` is something like `"/path/to/module.py/../../"` which then gets repaired by [`os.path.normpath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath) (invoked through `os.path.abspath`). So why perform that detour in the first place?